# How to delete SSO information?

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, authentication

I have implemented the auth. provider SSO from Facebook.

When I disable a user, I want to delete at the same time the authentication information of Facebook(ex. Third-party account link in User object).

Is it possible?
How to way to be implemented in APEX?

Comment: I couldn't find any API for this and am presently having to manually click the "Revoke" action on the "Third-Party Account Links" of the User object. Would be interested in API if/when it exists.

Comment: Definitely post that as an answer @KeithC! The converse of "Third Party Account Links" is also available on user as "Connected Accounts" if a salesforce user is the identity (as opposed to a Facebook user)

Answer (score 1):

An API for revocation of Third Party Account Links was added in Winter 15 (API version 32.0)

> **ThirdPartyAccountLink**
>   A list of third-party account links is generated when users of an organization authenticate using an external Auth. Provider. Use this object to list and revoke a given user's social sign-on connections (such as Facebook©).

[Winter 15 Release Notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_api_objects_new.htm)

However, based on limited testing, this does not currently seem to be fully supported from Apex. Some SOQL queries fail with unexpected errors and DML is not supported (confirmed by Salesforce support).

There is now an [idea for suporting revocation in Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnLlAAK).

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke the API Access but you cannot delete it. You can request access from Salesforce to make the object writable which grants access to delete the third-party links.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthToken.htm#apex_Auth_AuthToken_revokeAccess

From SFDC's documentation

> revokeAccess(authProviderId, providerName, userId, remoteIdentifier)
>   Revokes the access token for a specified social sign-on user from a
>   third-party service such as Facebook©. Note that querying the
>   ProviderType field on the AuthProvider object sometimes returns a
>   value that differs from the expected provider name value. For example,
>   for Open ID Connect providers, OpenIdConnect is the ProviderType value
>   for the AuthProvider object, but the expected providerName is Open ID
>   Connect. Signature public static Boolean revokeAccess(String
>   authProviderId, String providerName, String userId, String
>   remoteIdentifier)
>
> Parameters authProviderId Type: String The ID of the Auth. Provider in
>   the Salesforce organization. providerName Type: String The proper name
>   of the third party. For all providers except Janrain, the expected
>   values are Facebook Salesforce Open ID Connect Microsoft Access
>   Control Service LinkedIn Twitter Google For Janrain providers, the
>   parameter value is the proper name of the third party used. Yahoo! is
>   an example of a Janrain provider value. userId Type: String The
>   15-character ID for the user whose access is being revoked.
>   remoteIdentifier Type: String The unique ID for the user in the
>   third-party system (this value is in the associated
>   ThirdPartyAccountLink standard object). Return Value Type: Boolean
>
> The return value is true if the revokeAccess() operation is
>   successful; otherwise false.
>
> Example The following example revokes a Facebook user's access token.

```
Auth.AuthToken.revokeAccess('0SOxx00000#####', 'facebook', '005xx00000#####', 'ThirdPartyIdentifier_exist214176560#####');
```